# Non-Abelian Lie Group from Abelian Group

Tags: lie-groups, abelian-groups

Does any one know if there is a way of constructing a non-Abelian 
Lie Group from Abelian Lie groups beyond using a semi-direct product?

I don't think so but there may be some pathological cases or obscure theorem out there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "from"?

Comment: Ok, that is not good wording. What I mean is: 

can I construct a non-Abelian Lie group using (? better wording) abelian groups some how. i.e. one possibility is using a semi-direct product of abelian groups to form an non-Abelian group. But I am wondering if there is another alternative.

Comment: Yes, you can consider extensions that are not semidirect products.

Comment: Thank you, could you possibly direct me to an example or reference please?